# git fetch branches with specified prefix

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

I have following branches in remote origin.

```
ft_d_feature_abc
ft_d_feature_xyz
ft_d_feature_lam
ft_d_feature_ton
ft_m_feature_mak
ft_m_feature_echo
ft_m_feature_laa
ft_m_feature_pol
```

I want to fetch branches which are starting with `ft_d`. How can I achieve this with `git fetch`?
My Git version is 1.7.9.5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Git version 2.6, you can specify partial substrings (with simple glob-style matching) in a fetch or push refspec.  Hence:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/heads/ft_d*:refs/remotes/origin/ft_d*'
```

would do what you are asking for.  Generalized regular expressions are *not* available, nor generalized globs: only the one specific case of `*` matching everything between two fixed strings is allowed.  (Some fixed strings here may be empty.  Usually the back half is, i.e., we usually fetch `refs/heads/*`, not `refs/heads/*x` to get just branches whose name ends in `x`.)

If your Git is older than 2.6, there is no simple way to do this in one fetch.  You will need multiple fetches, in a loop, and you will need to do your own name-matching, perhaps using the output from `git ls-remote`.

(Of course, `git fetch origin` will normally just bring *everything* over, as specified in the `remote.origin.fetch` configuration entry or entries, and in most cases there's little point in constraining `git fetch` this way.  Are you sure you want to bother?)

Comment: My Git version is 1.7.9.5. I am going to update my git and will check this.

Comment: This works. As I am new to git I was not able to understand this completely. I had to read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec to understand this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Git supports regexes for fetching a branch, however, you can create a simple script that does it for you:

```
for i in {1..3};
do
    git fetch origin ft_d_feature$i
done
```

Comment: for simplicity I wrote feature1,2,3. There is no sequence in my branch names. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is list your remote branches:

```
PREFIX='ft_d_feature_'

for BRANCH in $(git branch | cut -c 3-); do
    if [[ $BRANCH = $PREFIX* ]] ; then
        echo $BRANCH;
    fi
done
```

**Edit**

To actually call `git fetch` for each branch:

```
PREFIX='ft_d_feature_'

for BRANCH in $(git branch | cut -c 3-); do
    if [[ $BRANCH = $PREFIX* ]] ; then
        git fetch origin $BRANCH
    fi
done
```

**Edit2**

Another way is creating a git alias, you can add it in your `~/.gitconfig` file.

```
[alias]
     fetch-prefix = "!f(){ for BRANCH in $(git branch | cut -c 3-); do case $BRANCH in $1*) git fetch origin $BRANCH; esac; done; }; f"
```

Usage:
   `git fetch-prefix ft_d_feature_`